# A signal that can't be overridden?

Tags: linux, signals

Which signal can't be overridden in linux?

Comment: SIGKILL (9) for example.

Comment: `The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.` - from `man 7 signal`.

Answer (score 1):

From man 7 signal:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.